# React Context Reducer Dispatches Overwriting the other when called

Tags: reactjs, state, reducers, react-context

I have a video uploader that uploads videos in context so that you can move around the application while its uploading. After upload, it calls a listener that runs to check status of the progress of the video. If I try to add another video to the queue which is stored as state.files and the listener is running, when the listener updates the state.files array item it while i try to add the new video in another dispatch, the new video dissapears. How can I update state on the same prop if they both happen at the same time. Here is what I am using now for the interval event to check video progress:

```
const checkTranscode = () =>{

const vals = {
  account_id: videoState.user.account,
}

axios.all([
  axios.post('/endpoint1', vals), 
  axios.post('/endpoint2', vals)
])
.then(axios.spread((data1, data2) => {

  let id:number
  let prop:any
  let value:any

  data1.data.map(function(qfile:any){
    videoState.files.map(function(file:any, idx:number){
      if(qfile.uuid === file.uuid){
        if(qfile.percent_complete && qfile.percent_complete > 0 && qfile.status === 'TRANSCODING'){
          id = idx
          prop = 'file_status'
          value = 'Transcoding'
          dispatch({ type: 'update-file-item', file, id, prop, value })
          prop = 'transcode_progress'
          value = Math.ceil(qfile.percent_complete)
          dispatch({ type: 'update-file-item', file, id, prop, value })
        }

        if(!qfile.percent_complete){
          id = idx
          prop = 'transcode_progress'
          value = 0
          dispatch({ type: 'update-file-item', file, id, prop, value })
        }
        
        if(qfile.status === 'TRANSCRIBING'){
          id = idx
          prop = 'file_status'
          value = 'Transcribing'
          dispatch({ type: 'update-file-item', file, id, prop, value })
        }

      }
    })
  })

  data2.data.map(function(qfile:any){
    videoState.files.map(function(file:any, idx:number){
      if(qfile.uuid === file.uuid){
    
        if(file.file_status === 'Transcribing' && qfile.status === 'READY'){
          id = idx
          dispatch({ type: 'remove-file-by-id', id })
        }

        if(qfile.status === 'STORED' && file.storage){
          id = idx
          dispatch({ type: 'remove-file-by-id', id })
        }
      }
    })
  })
}));

}
```

Then the add file from drop in container:

```
addFilesFromDrop: (dropFiles:any) =>{
      const existingFiles = videoState.files
      const arrFiles = Array.from(dropFiles)
      let exists = false
      let newId = videoState.maxId
      const newFiles = arrFiles.map((file:any) => {

        if(existingFiles.length > 0){
          existingFiles.map((efile) =>{
            const newFile:any = file
            
            if(efile.file){
              if(efile.file.name === newFile.name){
                exists = true
              }
            }else{
              //errored uploads will not have a file
              if(efile.original_filename === newFile.name){
                exists = true
              }
            }
          })
        }
        newId++
        const src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
        return { file, id: newId, src, file_status:'Ready' }
      })
      if(!exists){
        const maxId = newId
        const file = newFiles
        dispatch({ type: 'add-file-to-list', file, maxId})
      }else{
        return
      }
          
    }
```

And the reducer actions look like this:

```
case 'add-file-to-list':
      return { 
        ...state, 
        files:[...state.files, action.file],
        maxId: action.maxId
      }

case 'update-file-item':
      const index = state.files.findIndex(file => file.id !== action.id);
      const newArray = [...state.files];
      newArray[index][action.prop] = action.value
      return { 
        ...state, 
        files: newArray
      }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot the spread on my update -

```
case 'add-file-to-list':
      return { 
        ...state, 
        files:[...state.files,...action.files],
        maxId: action.maxId
      }
```

This fixed it.